# Can I submit a form and add record to DB by only php in the same file without using Get/Post methods?

Tags: php, forms, submit

Say I have create a registration form. Now to add records into a DB, we send the data to another php file by POST method, where we do some validations and add a record. Is it possible to do it in the same file without sending and getting the data by POST/GET? If no, then why?

EDIT: Even sending to the same php file is SENDING and losing resource. I ask this question because I want to avoid the lost of time on sending by GET/POST and getting by the same Get/POST. And if it is not posible, I want to understand why PHP does not allow.

Comment: I wish I could know why a down vote is done.

Comment: im going to guess youre getting downvoted because the question is "silly". A web application in any language is a client server application. Eventually you have to send/receive data to/from the server for whatever purpose. Its jsut how it works, period. I dont agree with the down votes because its a valid question (unless we are going to start being knowledge snobs...) for a beginner, but your points seem to suggest this is something you would know by now... it seems unavoidable :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You always have to send data from the client to the server, there is no way around that.

If you dont want to reload the entire page the user is on, you could submit the data via AJAX to the php file responsible for processing it and adding the data. That way the user never leaves the page.

Comment: Its not php.... its the same in any client server/application, though you might be using a raw tcp stream or something instead of an http post or whatever... But you still send data back and forth bewtween the two because they need to communicate for whatever reason(s).

Answer (score 1):

yes ofcourse.

just in your form "action" put

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

then in the beginning of your PHP page check if the $_POST is set or not

```
if(isset($_POST))
{
   // actions to be taken after form submission
}
```

ofcourse you can add a hidden input tag for refining checks for the $_POST. eg in your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="formSubmit" value="yes" />
```

then your check should be like

```
if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']))
{
       // actions to be taken after form submission
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. For example:

```
<?php
if(true === isset($_POST['submit']) // check if submit-button was clicked
{
    // do some validation here...

    // If validation successes add record into db here...
}
else // no post data sent so output the form
{
    // output the form here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is easy. The form can post back to its self. This is most easily done by not even specifying the value of action in the form tag.

```
<form method='POST'>
```

Then at the top of the page before any content is put on the page, include an if statement to check if the form was submitted.

```
if (isset ($_POST['post'])) { // 'post' is the name of the submit button
    $error = false;
    // Do validation
```

From there do validation and act according to the result.
If you have lots of validation to do, perhaps put that in another file and include it.

```
    include "formValidation.php";
```

If all is well and all tests are passed use

```
    if ($error === false) {
        Header ("Location: confirmation.php"); 
        exit;
    }
}
```

If tests fail, stay on the page keeping all the post data, and display an error.

```
if (isset ($error) && !empty ($error)) {
    echo "<div class='error'>$error</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible set

> action="same page"

in form tag.
you can access your all form attributes on same page.